# Why the function withUpperCase is returned from upperCase?

Tags: javascript, function

Could you explain, please? Why the function `withUpperCase()` is returned from `upperCase`? Probably, I don't understand so well the expression `const withUpperCase = upperCase()`. Are we just assigning the `upperCase()` function to  `const withUpperCase`, so `withUpperCase` becomes a function? And how does it work when when we call `withUpperCase('I love coding')` and returned from `upperCase`? Thank you

```
const toUpperCase = (string) => string.toUpperCase();
const toExtend = (string) => `${string}!`;
const toRepeat = (string) => string.repeat(3);

const upperCase = (...fns) => firstItem => fns.reduce((acc, currentValue) => currentValue(acc), firstItem)

const withUpperCase = upperCase(
    toUpperCase,
    toExtend,
    toRepeat
);

console.log(withUpperCase(' I love coding'));
```

Comment: Where did this code come from?

Comment: I dunno is it allowed to post other resources on StackOverflow, but it is from the article on the theme of composition in js

Comment: Well `upperCase()` returns a function. That's why you can call `withUpperCase()` as a function.

Comment: `upperCase` is a really strange name for that variable, because it actually has nothing to do with making something upper case. The function stored in `upperCase` takes functions as arguments, and returns a new functions which will apply those functions one after the other. It would make more sense to call `upperCase` something like `chainStringTransformations`.